# Having issues with print statement formatting

Tags: python, printing, formatting, statements

I have this code which works properly but I cannot figure out how to get it to format correctly.

```
from Stack import*

def main():

file=input("Enter the name of the file containing postfix expressions: ")
file=open(file, 'r')

stack=Stack()

operators=["/", "*", "-", "+"]

for line in file:

    try:

        print("Expression: " ,line)
        expression=line.split()
        for i in expression:
            if i not in operators:
                stack.push(i)

            if i == "/":
                x=int(stack.pop())
                y=int(stack.pop())
                stack.push(y/x)

            if i == "*":
                x=int(stack.pop())
                y=int(stack.pop())
                stack.push(x*y)

            if i == "+":
                x=int(stack.pop())
                y=int(stack.pop())
                stack.push(x+y)

            if i == "-":
                x=int(stack.pop())
                y=int(stack.pop())
                stack.push(y-x)

        if stack.size() > 1:
            print("Error: ",line,"is an invalid postfix expression")
        else:
            print("Answer: " ,stack.pop())


    except IndexError:
        print("Error: ",line,"is an invalid postfix expression.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: ",line,"is an invalid postfix expression.")
main()
```

But the out put comes out all gross looking like this:
I don't think it is extremely important that it looks nice but I would like for it to.

```
Enter the name of the file containing postfix expressions: expressions.txt
Expression:  5 4 3 + 2 * -

Answer:  -9
Expression:  8 5 *

Answer:  40
Expression:  20 5 /

Answer:  4.0
Expression:  3 8 6 + *

Answer:  42
Expression:  3 4 + 9 - 12 +

Answer:  10
Expression:  9 3 2 1 + + /

Answer:  1.5
Expression:  3 + 4

Error:  3 + 4
 is an invalid postfix expression.
Expression:  * 3 4 5 + *

Error:  * 3 4 5 + *
 is an invalid postfix expression.
Expression:  4 9 1 3 + -

Error:  4 9 1 3 + -
 is an invalid postfix expression
Expression:  h 3 +

Error:  h 3 +
 is an invalid postfix expression.
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a \n newline character stuck at the end of the strings from your file. Try stripping that off using python's str.strip() function.

Comment: to further this answer he means try `print("Error: ",line.strip(),"is an invalid postfix expression")`  (+1 though since this is exactly the right answer)

Comment: That was it. I completely forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Printing elements like that will get you additional spaces that it sounds like you don't want.

```
>>> print('a', 'b')
a b
```

So, you'll want to change

```
print("Error: ",line,"is an invalid postfix expression.")
```

to

```
print("Error:", line, "is an invalid postfix expression.")
```

Similarly, change

```
print("Answer: " ,stack.pop())
```

to

```
print("Answer:", stack.pop())
```

**Note**: I've moved the commas to be more standard but that difference doesn't have any effect.

[More information here, including how to use the `end` parameter.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) You might also benefit from string formatting operations, information about which can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: nice thorough answer ... unfortunately doesn't really address the OP's question

Comment: OP didn't specify whether he was looking to change the additional newlines or the extra spaces. Regardless, he now has answers for both.